# PHP + htaccess: Protecting PDF Files

Tags: php, sql, ajax, apache, .htaccess

I have a my website set up right now so a user must be logged in (PHP + Cookies + SQL) in order to see a list of what files are available to them. However, the files are uploaded in a predictable directory format that, once a user knows the URL, could expose said files to an unauthorized user. They are simply PDFs. I'm curious to how I should protect the directory, but I'm assuming it will be with .htaccess. The files are linked using simple dynamic  tags that are pulled from a database. Is there a safe and effective way to protect a whole directory and allow logged in users to quickly view the link, but redirect unauthorized users to a login screen? Thanks!

Zach

Answer (score 3):

The only real safe way to do this is to put the files outside of the working web directory and serve them to logged in users through a php file.  If you want the files to still retain the .pdf extension you could use htaccess to rewrite incoming pdf names to your php file + a few params.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+).pdf$ index.php?filename=$1 [L,QSA]
```

index.php:

```
if($logged_in){

    $temp_file = $_GET['filename'];

   //make sure no one is trying to inject anything funny
    $temp_file = str_replace('.','',$temp_file);                //prevent file path manipulation
    $temp_file = str_replace('/','',$temp_file);                //prevent file path manipulation
    $temp_file = str_replace('%00','',$temp_file);              //prevent null char injector
    $temp_file = preg_replace('[^A-Za-z0-9]', '', $temp_file ); //just to be sure

 $file = STORAGE_DIR.$temp_file.'pdf';

  if (file_exists(file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
  }
}
else{

    header('Location: '.LOGIN_PAGE);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This looks like a possibility. Only concern I have is that my system uses <a> tags with PHP filling in the 'href' path after pulling the list from a database. Is there a way to incorporate this method into an <a> tag?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, if you implement this method correctly your links should not need to change.  If your database pulls a url called yourdomain.com/pdf-files/example.pdf you would just move all the pdf files in the pdf-files directory outside the working web directory and then install the script and htaccess file inside pdf-files.

Comment: +1 for the untainting :)

Comment: @MarkR: Ok thanks! Is STORAGE_DIR declared in my configuration file?

Comment: Yep declare it where you like, it's just the system path to the folder where you'd like to store the PDFs. You'd also define LOGIN_PAGE the same way, but make that a web directory.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure directory listing is disabled for your web server. This ensures that no one can view a list of all your files.

Secondly, name the files in such way that its hard for someone to guess. Don't use simple database id (e.g. 1.pdf etc) - either use a hash value of some sort or a name that makes some sense but not easily guessable.

You could use a combination of database id, timestamp, random value, and tags. For example:

```
top-secret-document-20120216-77-33.pdf
```

Of course, James Bond would move the sensitive files outside the web tree and have a php script that reads and outputs the file for a logged in user.

EDIT: Now that you mention sensitive files, then you really ought to think more about this. You could look into moving the files into the database. And/or checking cookies in htaccess.

Comment: Hi Zaf,

Thanks for the reply. The file names aren't necessarily easy to guess, but they have sensitive information and I was hoping for a solution that would fully protect them to an unauthorized user (.htaccess hopefully)...

Comment: @Zakman411 I've added something about moving the files into the database. You could check for for cookies in htaccess as well.

Comment: The hashed names works especially well if you remove the webserver's ability to read directory contents via filesystem permissions: `chmod 711 /path/to/secret/directory` (assuming the owner _isn't_ the webserver user account). Only `x` execute access is required to _traverse_ directories.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to serve the files using PHP and disallow access to PDF files directly via your .htaccess file using FilesMatch.

If you need me to expound further on how to do this, let me know.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|pdf)$">
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: yeah this would be great - any help?

Comment: Mark R's answer actually has the PHP material you'd need and a rewrite rule that would work, but you don't need to worry about putting the files outside of your web root as long as you add the code that I added to my answer to your .htaccess file.

You should, realistically, place the FilesMatch code in an .htaccess file in the directory the PDFs are stored in so it doesn't inadvertently affect files you don't want to deny access to.

Comment: Would you mind posting that in your answer? I'd actually prefer to not move the files outside the web root (I'm using CPanel and I'm not sure that's possible).

Comment: The FilesMatch code is already in my answer, so just create an .htaccess file in the directory where you're storing PDFs and add the code I posted there. Then, use a PHP file similar to Mark R's, but with user authentication and verification added, to serve the files.

Comment: @DanAmbrisco, dear i created a file(.htaccess) on the folder where i upload(file.pdf)s, same as before,with keep the code you wrote, if i comment the uploading type validation means PDF one, it will upload any file to that folder, so what is real use of you .httaccess code????

Answer (score 0):

I have the bare bones of a PHP-based download system, to which user security could be easily added. It's [here](http://blog.jondh.me.uk/2011/07/bandwidth-project-offering-direct-downloads-without-breaking-limits/) if you want to take a look. It uses Symfony 1.3 and Propel, so you can connect it to a wide variety of databases. No F/OSS license yet, but I'll add one if you want!